# remove words based on first letter using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to remove all words that start with "a" in a string.

Input:

```
string <- "This is a sentence about nothing."
```

My attempt:

```
stringr::str_remove_all(string,"a*\\b")
```

output I got:

```
[1] "This is  sentence about nothing."
```

output I want:

```
[1] "This is sentence nothing."
```

I am not sure how to detect based on one letter but perform action(e.g., remove, replace) on the whole word. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: it works! Thank you! I wonder why didn't "a*\\b" work?

Comment: I explained that bit in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a*\b` pattern matches zero or more `a` chars followed with end of string or a word char. It does not match a word unless it is an `a` word.

You can use

```r
stringr::str_remove_all(string,"\\ba\\w*")
stringr::str_replace_all(string,"\\ba\\w*", "")
gsub("\\ba\\w*", "", string, perl=TRUE) ## ASCII only letters/digits
```

where `\ba\w*` matches a word boundary, `a`, and then zero or more word chars.

If you also want to remove any whitespaces before the word, add `\s*` at the start:

```r
stringr::str_remove_all(string,"\\s*\\ba\\w*")
stringr::str_replace_all(string,"\\s*\\ba\\w*", "")
gsub("\\s*\\ba\\w*", "", string, perl=TRUE) ## ASCII only letters/digits/whitespaces
```

If you need to make sure you only remove natural langugage words consisting only of letters, then you can replace `\w` with `\p{L}`:

```r
stringr::str_remove_all(string,"\\s*\\ba\\p{L}*")
stringr::str_replace_all(string,"\\s*\\ba\\p{L}*", "")
gsub("(*UCP)\\s*\\ba\\p{L}*", "", string, perl=TRUE) ## any Uncicode letters/digits/whitespaces
```